# Coding of unsigned int to prevent guessing next ID

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, protocol-design, format-preserving

Suppose we are assigning records an unsigned integer ID from a N-bit space (say 32-bit) in a sequential manner. Is there a way we can code this ID before showing it to the public such that someone can't guess the next ID in the sequence. It should be two-way, such that given the coded int, we can determine the original ID and 1:1 such that every ID has exactly one corresponding coded int (ideally of the same bit-length).

This doesn't need to hold up to any kind of brute force attack, but should be non-obvious to viewers if two coded integers represent IDs close together or far apart.

Any ideas? The simpler the implementation the better.

Comment: Either use a 32 bit blockcipher like Skip32 or use proper format preserving encryption (tricky to implement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few approaches:

- Generic [format preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). For example AES in FFX mode.

  The downsides of this approach are complexity and performance.
- Block-ciphers with small (typically 32 bit) blocks.

  - Skip32 derived from Skipjack
  - [ipcrypt](https://github.com/veorq/ipcrypt) (very recent, no security analysis so far)

  The downside of this approach is that these ciphers aren't very popular and probably haven't seen much analysis.
- Shuffling algorithms like thorp shuffle of swap-or-not.

Comment: I first thought that ipcrypt was not very interesting, I could not even find a paper on it. But a quick search found that the author is Jean-Philippe Aumasson of Blake(2) fame, and based on SipHash. Reputable, but indeed, no security analysis and no paper.

Comment: Skip32 is EXACTLY what I am looking for. I quickly found a javascript implementation at npmjs.com/package/skip32 which can be quite literally dropped into my existing application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[swap-or-not](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~morris/shuffle.pdf) seems perfect for your use case.

Comment: Indeed. Or any block cipher with a small block, as common in [Format-Preserving Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). I have re-tagged the question accordingly. Following that tag will lead to many related questions with good answers.

Comment: Thank you Ricky I will read that article and explore other format-preserving encryption questions mentioned by @fgrieu. Thanks!